# partial_fit function in sklearn Multi Layer Perceptron

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron

I'm training a Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP) (with default options) in `scikit-learn` using the `partial_fit(X,y)` function and I notice that there is a difference between calling

```
partial_fit([X1],[y1])
partial_fit([X2],[y2])
```

and

```
partial_fit([X1,X2],[y1,y2])
```

The second option seems faster but the result seems worse.
Can someone explain me what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult to answer the question without a minimal, reproducible example but here's my take.

A sklearn perceptron has an attribute [`batch_size`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) which has a default value of 200. When you set `verbose=True` of your `MLPClassifier`, you will see that your first example (two consecutive calls) results in two iterations, while the 2nd example results in one iteration, i.e. the the 2nd `partial_fit` call improves the result from the first call. In each iteration the total sample is split into chunks again.

When you have a small sample_size (<5000 in the snippet below), the default `batch_size` is too big relative to the sample size, reducing it to 100 will give better results for both approaches but there won't be a difference between the consecutive calls and the one line approach.

This artifact disappears with higher sample numbers (>10^6).

[image]

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_mlp(resize_batch, n):
    mlp = MLPClassifier(verbose=True, random_state=random_state)
    if resize_batch:
        mlp.batch_size = min(n // 2, 100)
    return mlp

n_samples = [10**2, 10**3, 5*10**3, 10**4, 10**5, 10**6, 10**7]
batch_resize = [False, True]
random_state = 1

results = list()

for n in n_samples:
    x = make_moons(n_samples=n, noise=0.3, random_state=random_state)
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x[0])
    results.append([n])
    for resize in batch_resize:
        mlp = get_mlp(resize, n)
        mlp.partial_fit(X, x[1], [0, 1])
        results[-1].append([mlp.score(X, x[1]), 0, resize])

        mlp = get_mlp(resize, n)
        for i in range(2):

            train_start = i * n // 2
            train_stop = (i + 1) * n // 2
            mlp.partial_fit(X[train_start:train_stop], x[1][train_start:train_stop], [0, 1])
        results[-1].append([mlp.score(X, x[1]), 1, resize])

x = [i[0] for i in results]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black']
labels = ['one call, batch=auto', 'two calls, batch=auto', 'one call, batch=100', 'two calls, batch=100']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
handles = list()
for n in range(4):
    plt.subplot(210 + i)
    handles.append(plt.plot(x, [i[n + 1][0] for i in results], c=colors[n], label=labels[n])[0])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The solver 'lbfgs' of the multi-layers perceptron doesn't use minibatch.  Is it a good idea to use this solver in order to avoid to find the optimal value of `batch_size` ? ( I use `partial_fit(X,y)` for reinforcement learning, thus I don't know in advance the number of iteration)

Comment: But the other solver might perform worse than the others. I'd suggest trying to the find the best solver with its optimal parameters.